# In povray, is there a way to sum the light hitting a surface area into a value?

Tags: povray

I am simulating different light pipes and would like to quantify the amount of light hitting the area under the light pipe.  Is there a way in povray to quantify the amount of light (down to a single value) hitting a specific area of a surface?